# Decentralized Data Storage System in NXT - How do you disable the 2 week data pruning?

Tags: nxt, decentralization, storage, pruning, ardor

Currently the NXT platform has the ability to store data in its blockchain, whereby making it a decentralized data storage system. But the thing is that the data is purged from a nodes blockchain every 2 weeks to reduce bloat and only keeps a hash of the file only. I read that you can host nodes that disable this pruning of the data and keep the data indefinitely. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can disable data pruning by editing the config file at **conf/nxt-default.properties**

This would effectively make the node into an **NXT Archival Data Node** and I'd imagine you would be able to charge to retrieve old data in the future.

```
# Override the lifetime of prunable data to keep them longer, value in seconds.
# Set to -1 to disable pruning. Has no effect if set to less then the minimum
# required lifetime of two weeks (1209600 seconds) on mainnet, or 24 hours
# (86400 seconds) on testnet.
nxt.maxPrunableLifetime=0

# Always include prunable parts in transaction json, as long as still available,
# even if expired.
nxt.includeExpiredPrunable=false
```

Just change it to **-1** and **true** in those settings.